# Incorrect output while comparing two strings C++

Tags: c++, string, vector, iterator, compare

I have class CPerson that in simple looks like this:

```
CPerson
{
public:
   CPerson();
   pair<string, string> CP_surname_name;
   vector<CCar> CP_CarList;
};
```

then I have a `vector<CPerson> CR_people`
It's sorted vector by pair CP_surname_name.
The problem is, when I need to compare surname and name, inputted by user firstly I go throug vector, if there is already the person I am looking for.

```
auto it = lower_bound(CR_people.begin(), CR_people.end(), surname_name);
```

I have overriden operator< so sorting is fine.
But when I need to check, if the surname_name is exact the same as CP_surname_name by:

```
if(surname_name == (*it).CP_surname_name){...}
```

it gives me `false`even they are same.
I already tried:

```
if(surname_name.first == (*it).CP_surname_name.first && surname_name.second == (*it).CP_surname_name.second){...}
```

and it works the same.
I also tried `strcmp()` but it gives me errors, because I am using string, not char* so I tried append `.c_str()` to retype it, and that gave me also wrong results. The compare() in String class did not work as well.
Thanks for any help, and sorry for my bad english.

The part of code:

```
bool CRegister::AddCar( const string & rz, const string & name, const string & surname )
{
pair<string, string> SurName = make_pair(surname, name);
CCar newCar = CCar(rz, SurName);

if(CR_people.size() == 0 && CR_cars.size() == 0)
{
    CR_people.push_back(CPerson(name,surname,rz));
    CR_cars.push_back(newCar);
    return true;
}
else if(CR_people.size() != 0 && CR_cars.size() != 0)
{
    auto it = lower_bound(CR_cars.begin(), CR_cars.end(), rz);

    if( it < CR_cars.end() && (*it).CC_rz.c_str() == rz.c_str()){return false;}
    CR_cars.insert(it, newCar);

    auto it2 = lower_bound(CR_people.begin(), CR_people.end(), SurName);

    if( (*it2).CP_SnNm.first.c_str() == SurName.first.c_str() && (*it2).CP_SnNm.second.c_str() == SurName.second.c_str())
    {
        cout << "Cannot get here" << endl;
        if((*it2).CPAddCar(rz))
            return true;
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        CR_people.insert(it2, CPerson(name, surname, rz));
        return true;
    }

    throw "Error, Add Car to register";
    return false;
}
return false;
```

}

The meaning of code is, when I have the person in my list already, I just Add CCar to the CPersons list of cars, and when there is no person equal of th parameters, I add CPerson with CCar in it list.

Comment: How is `surname_name` declared? What is its contents (how is it initialized)?

Comment: How have you implemented operator < ?

Comment: `pair<string, string> surname_name = make_pair(surname, name)` where `surname` and `name` are string entered by user.
Yes I have overriden the operator< for type of`pair<string,string>`.

Comment: And as a sanity check, are you making sure you use make_pair(surname,name) to store entered names and not make_pair(name,surname)?

Comment: Yes :) about this I was making myself sure for 5 times minimum

Comment: I even made a `cout` right before the comparison and the strings that should be compared were exactly the same, so I really don't know where is it failing.

Comment: Instead of paraphrasing an explanation of what you already did, show the actual code. What you describe sounds like it should work. If it doesn't, it means that the code is wrong. But without seeing the code, nobody will be able to tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `string::compare()` method to compare two strings?

Comment: @PraneethNilangaPeiris: Why? What's wrong with `operator==`?

Comment: I appended the part of code. operator== and compare() are almost the same I think. And I've tried them both.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley : Sorry for that. Cz I couldn't see == overloaded in string class (But apparently it seems that somewhere else it had) and string comparison is not widely used using ==. It seems I was wrong. Sorry.

Comment: I may be being too picky, but `auto` was introduced in C++11, so maybe that tag would be useful?

Comment: I am compiling with g++ with parameter -std=c++11, so I think it should be a problem.